# Connecting Keyboard to Audacity

Tags: recording, keyboard, audio, audacity

I 've tried to connect my Ketron keyboard to the hp laptop which only has only a headphone jack meaning a port with the headphone logo on it.

I want to know how to connect the audio of the keyboard to audacity as well?

The keyboard has a headphone, line out, and microphone as its output. There is no USB on the keyboard.

When I go-to devices on the sound menu on my laptop I could only see the default devices the same thing on audacity as well.

If anyone could please assist me would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Which model is your Ketron keaboard?

Comment: Typically a headphone socket is output seen from the laptop, while you require an input. If a full headset i.e. including microphone can be connected to it - check in the manual - a special plug may be able to reach the input part.

Answer (score 1):

You usually want to use the line out of your keyboard.

In most cases you will have to get an audio interface. It will allow you to connect a line output (like your keyboard) to the interface, which will be connected via usb to your pc.

Which size is the line out of your keyboard? Is it 3.5mm or 6.35mm? Audio interfaces usually use 6.5mm.